# Javascript DOM manipulation, Each click creates a new li element

Tags: javascript, dom

I have an app with a few buttons, and every button has an element, button one has a "banana" and button 2 has an "apple", when the user clicks on those buttons, a new li element should be added to a list. Here is a JSFiddle with an example of the problem I'm running into:

https://jsfiddle.net/ejha3q94/

Only 1 li is created with every click and the elements are just added on that same li.

```
 var newElement = document.createElement("li");
 var newElText = document.createTextNode ("");

 document.getElementById("itemOne").addEventListener("click", function() {
  newElText = document.createTextNode("Banana");
   document.getElementById("list").appendChild(newElement).appendChild(newElText);

 });

 document.getElementById("itemTwo").addEventListener("click", function() {
  newElText = document.createTextNode("Apple");
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(newElement).appendChild(newElText);

  });
```

How can I make it so every click is a new li element using only Javascript?

Comment: `appendChild` "cuts"  the element from its current location. You've to [clone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) `newElement`, and append the clone instead of the original.

Comment: What you say makes sense, I fixed it by adding the "var newElement = document.createElement("li");" after each of the functions, so every function call creates a new "clone". Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can't reuse elements by reassigning them. You have to create a new element each time you wish to insert a new element into the DOM.

This solution creates a generic function `addItem` for your procedure. You can see all the element creation and DOM manipulation in one place.

```js
// element references
var list = document.getElementById('list');
var appleBtn = document.getElementById('apple');
var bananaBtn = document.getElementById('banana');

// DOM manipulating function
function addItem(listElem, text) {
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  var textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
  listElem.appendChild(li).appendChild(textNode);
}

// event listeners
appleBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  addItem(list, 'apple');
});
bananaBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  addItem(list, 'banana');
});
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>

<button id="apple">Apple</button>
<button id="banana">Banana</button>
```

But even repeating `addItem(list, *)` can get repetitious too. Plus, we don't necessarily need one event listener *per* button. Wouldn't it be nice if we could just use a *single* event listener to handle all of the cases?

The solution below uses a `data-*` attribute to store each button's contribution to the list. Then, using [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) we handle **all** buttons with a single event listener (function).

```js
// element references
var list = document.getElementById('list');
var buttons = document.getElementById('buttons');

// single #buttons event delegate
buttons.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  // event.target contains the element that was clicked
  var item = event.target.dataset.item;
  if (item === undefined) return false;
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  var textNode = document.createTextNode(item);
  list.appendChild(li).appendChild(textNode);
});
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>

<div id="buttons">
  <button data-item="apple">Apple</button>
  <button data-item="banana">Banana</button>
  <button data-item="orange">Orange</button>
  <button data-item="grape">Grape</button>
  <button data-item="plum">Plum</button>
</div>
```

Comment: ``appleBtn`` and ``bananaBtn`` are never used, and adding functions just over complicates the answer.

Comment: @seahorsepip `appleBtn` and `bananaBtn` *are* used in the event listeners. Adding a function does not over-complicate things. it removes code duplication. See @guest271314's answer for the kind of duplication I'm talking about. Now imagine we have a dozen buttons to add items to the list...

Comment: Ah my bad I didn't see that you used the variables for the event listeners. And for dozens of buttons it's a not a bad idea to use a function but it might be better to use classes and data-attributes instead in that case.

Comment: @seahorsepip *"might be better to use classes and a data-attribute"* – and.... and ?....  a **function**. You're only fooling yourself if you think you can use an event listener without a function.

Comment: @naomik _"See @ guest271314's answer for the kind of duplication I'm talking about."_ See updated post.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that var `newElement` and `newElText` is created or cloned on every click instead of referenced: https://jsfiddle.net/ejha3q94/2/

Otherwise it won't create a new list element but modifies the existing list element every time.

```
document.getElementById("itemOne").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var newElement = document.createElement("li");
    var newElText = document.createTextNode("Banana");
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(newElement).appendChild(newElText);
});

document.getElementById("itemTwo").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var newElement = document.createElement("li");
    var newElText = document.createTextNode("Apple");
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(newElement).appendChild(newElText);
});
```

Comment: Please don't use off-site code pasting services when it's possible to embed the pastes right here. StackOverflow has html/css/js snippets that can demo your code without adding potential for link rot.

Comment: @naomik The exact same code is embedded in the answer, there's nothing wrong about using offsite linking in that case.

Comment: Having runnable code here is a big gain for readers. Taking readers off the site separates the code for your explanation – which is obviously important to you since you criticized another post for offering a code-only answer.

Comment: naomik is talking about the Stack Snippet feature, in case you're not aware of it.

Comment: @squint correct. seahorsepip, I've demonstrated its use in my answer.

Comment: @squint I know about the stack snippet feature but I prefer JSFiddle since it has versioning in the url. The snippet functionality is an optional feature on SO not an enforced rule.

Comment: @seahorsepip: Weird. Why would you need versioning in an answer? You do have a revision history, if it's really important to see past versions.

Comment: @seahorsepip that's nice that you like jsfiddle, but you should be considering the needs of learners before your own

Comment: @squint I mean in my JSFiddle account I see a clear list of all the fiddles Ive ever made on every site(SO, forums etc).

Comment: @seahorsepip how does that benefit anyone other than you ? You realize your SO profile contains all of your answers too, right ?

Comment: Oh, I see. That makes sense I guess. I've not used the full breadth of features offered by jsFiddle. Up to you in the end.

Comment: @naomik There was never a embed method before in SO and now it's suddenly the end of the world if people prefer using different Fiddle sites, there are no rules broken, no people harmed and the code and explanation is still there in the answer. And I don't like going trough all my forum accounts and my SO account to see what code snippets I've written.

Comment: It's the end of the world ?

Comment: @seahorsepip *"There was never a embed method before"* – before what? SO snippets have been around for a long time. *"There was never jsfiddle before ... jsfiddle. And then we had jsfiddle."* – what does that even mean?

Comment: @naomik fwiw, jsfiddle does provide a procedure to echo ajax `POST` requests, though this can also be achieved at stacksnippets using `GET` requests, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288902/does-stack-overflow-have-an-echo-page-to-test-ajax-requests-inside-a-code-sni/. plnkr provides ability to create and link separate files at the editor. There is also apparently an issue with stacksnippets at chrome, chromium 54 http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333674/cant-view-input-part-of-snippet-editor

Answer (score 2):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll()` with selector `"[id^=item]"`; iterate elements using `for..of` loop; create the elements within `click` event handler; append `#text` node to `li` element using `HTMLElement.dataset` before appending `li` element to `ul` element

```html
<div id="itemOne" data-fruit="Banana">
  
</div>

<div id="itemTwo" data-fruit="Apple">
  
</div>
<ul id="list"> </ul>
<script>
var list = document.getElementById("list");
for (el of document.querySelectorAll("[id^=item]")) {
  el.addEventListener("click", function() {
    list.appendChild(document.createElement("li"))
    .textContent = this.dataset.fruit;
  })
}
</script>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ejha3q94/4/

Comment: Explain your code. Just posting code without an explanation doesn't help.

Comment: Just FYI, your element creation can be a little less verbose... `list.appendChild(document.createElement("li")).textContent = this.dataset.fruit;`

Comment: @squint Nice. Updated

Comment: I didn't know that NodeLists were automatically iterable. That's great to know !

Answer (score 0):

There can only be a single `newElText` node. If you append it multiple times, it will just be moved. You should clone it manually:

```js
var newElement = document.createElement("li");
var list = document.getElementById("list");
document.getElementById("itemOne").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var newElText = document.createTextNode("Banana");
  list.appendChild(newElement.cloneNode(false)).appendChild(newElText);
});
document.getElementById("itemTwo").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var newElText = document.createTextNode("Apple");
  list.appendChild(newElement.cloneNode(false)).appendChild(newElText);
});
```

```html
<div id="itemOne"></div>
<div id="itemTwo"></div>
<ul id ="list"></ul>
```